# Jquery stop event from triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple scenario as shown in fiddle which is

Initially  event is `binded` on only one button A and `click` event is triggered in both the buttons(A & B) manually.

Now in event handler of button A the event handler for button B is binded. It is expected not to execute the callback of B as it is binded after the event is triggered.

But the callback is still executed. Where am i going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button class="a">botton A</button>
    <button class="b">button B</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('div').on('click', '.a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div').on('click', '.b', function () {
            alert('Can"t see me')
        });
    });
    $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/43q82xqv/)

EDIT: 
I have this scenario in my project and 
now I knew why is this happening :). **But how can i stop event from propagating?**

Comment: Instead of `$('button').trigger()` use `$('button.a').trigger('click');`

Comment: Why do you expect the event not to trigger if you trigger it manually? `$('button').trigger('click');`

Comment: You are triggering an event on button. So its binding events to class 'a' and 'b' both and triggering event for all button tags on page load.

Comment: You can do $('.a').trigger('click'); But why you are binding event to a div inside another event. Its causing binding same event multiple times (as many times as you click on A)?

Comment: @ShaunakD this is sample i have a situation where event is triggered on both the elements.

Answer (score 4):

`$('button').trigger('click');` triggers a click event on both buttons in the order they appear in the document markup. Since event bubbling is synchronous, the event for `.b` is binded before the click event is triggered on that button. Here's the breakdown:

1. `$('button')` creates a collection of button `.a` and button `.b`.
2. `.trigger('click');` iterates through each button in the collection and generates a click event.
3. button `.a` receives the click event and runs its event handler you registered for it on page load.
4. The event handler for `.b` is registered within the callback of the event handler for `.a`.
5. button `.b` receives the click event from `.trigger('click');` since it's second in the collection.
6. The callback of the event listener for button `.b` triggers the popup alert.

Since you only want to trigger button `.a` to be clicked, any of the following will work on your current document:

- `$('.a').trigger('click');`
- `$('button.a').trigger('click');` (though this is redundant)
- `$('button').get(0).trigger('click');` (since `.a` is the 0th indexed button element)

**EDIT** Although this is unrelated to the question, Perhaps you meant to register the event for `.b` only once, doing this:

`$('.a').one('click', function (e) {`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.a').one('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').on('click', '.b', function() {
      alert('Can\'t see me');
    });
  });
  $('.a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="a">button A</button>
  <button class="b">button B</button>
</div>
```

**SECOND EDIT** If you want to stop event propagation, you need to add another event listener, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.a').one('click', function() {
    $('.b').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      alert('Can see me');
    });
    $('div').on('click', '.b', function() {
      alert('Can\'t see me');
    });
  });
  $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="a">button A</button>
  <button class="b">button B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But how can i stop event from propagating?

Comment: @ezpura You can stop event propagation by calling ``e.stopPropagation();`` or ``e.stopImmediatePropagation();`` but that won't matter because ``$('button').trigger('click');`` creates two separate events. You can't stop the second event from within a callback of the first one.

Comment: @ezpura I added a second example to stop propagation

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `$('button').trigger('click');`.

This triggers a click on every button - first it clicks on `.a`, which binds the click handler to `.b`, then it clicks on `.b`.

In my experiment, simply putting button `.b` first fixed this, but I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: But how can i stop event from propagating?

Comment: The event is not propagating, there is more than one event.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the click is being triggered on all button instances serially...

`button a` click gets executed first...in its callback you bind `button b` click callback...

...then...`button b` click gets executed...hence callback for b gets executed...

All of this happens in that one call: `$('button').trigger('click');`

Edit: others have probably answered this before I have...but to iterate trigger the click on the correct element :

```
$('.a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: But how can i stop event from propagating?

Comment: @ezpura `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

The order of the execution is:

- bind .a
- trigger first button (say, a)
- callback for a: bind b
- trigger second button (b)
- callback for b

Even `$("button").trigger("click")` is a single line, it is a kind of *loop*, works like if it were:

```
var buttonElms = $("button");
for (var index in buttonElms) {
   buttonElms[index].trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Agree, but how to stop on triggering B after A callback is executed?

Comment: Trigger elms individually, one by one, so you can specify order, timing.